# xsl:template match doesn't match the specific xml tag as expected

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0, docbook

I have the following docbook xml file in version 5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book version="5.0" xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <info>
        <title>Title1</title>
        <cover>
            <para>
                <para>a paragraph</para>
            </para>
        </cover>
    </info>
    <!-- Part A -->
    <part>
        <title>Part A</title>
        <chapter label="1">
            <title role="HEAD-1">Chapter1 from PartA</title>
            <para role="richtext">
                <para role="richtext"> Text in paragraph </para>
            </para>
        </chapter>
        <chapter label="2">
            <title role="HEAD-1">Chapter2 from partA</title>
            <para>Another paragraph</para>
        </chapter>
    </part>
    <!-- Part B -->
    <part>
        <title>Part B</title>
        <chapter label="1">
            <title role="HEAD-1">Chapter1 from PartB</title>
            <section>
                <title role="HEAD-2">Section1 from Chapter1 of PartB</title>
                <para>a paragraph <ulink url="http://alink2">a link2</ulink></para>
            </section>
            <section>
                <title role="HEAD-2">Section2 from Chapter1 of PartB</title>
                <para>a paragraph <ulink url="http://alink2">a link2</ulink></para>
            </section>
        </chapter>
    </part>
</book>
```

I'm trying to convert it to html through xslt v3 and by modifying specific elements (
I have used the saxon xslt library for java) such as the title and the ulink, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
        xmlns:m="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook/modes"
        xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs db m h"
        version="3.0">

    <xsl:import href="https://cdn.docbook.org/release/xsltng/current/xslt/docbook.xsl" />

    <xsl:template match="db:ulink" mode="m:docbook">
        <xsl:variable name="url" select="@url"/>
        <xsl:variable name="name" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
        <a href="{$url}" title="{$name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$name" />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="db:title" mode="m:docbook">
        <xsl:variable name="header" select="@role"/>-->
        <xsl:variable name="title" select="normalize-space(.)"/>

        print something e.g. <xsl:value-of select="$title" />
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The ulink works as expected however I can't get the title correctly. I have tried different paths but with no success. A similar question was here [xsl:value-of not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72956288/xslvalue-of-not-working-in-docbook-xml-files/72957742) but it didn't help in this case.

The output I get is

```
<nav xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="top"></nav><main xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <article class="book">
      <header>
         <h1>Title1</h1>
      </header>
      <article class="part">
         <h1 class="title">Part A</h1>
         <article id="R_part1" class="part">
            <header>
               <h1><span class="label">Part<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span><span class="number">I<span class="sep">. </span></span>Part A</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="R_part1_ch1" class="chapter" db-label="1">
               <header>
                  <h1><span class="label">Chapter<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span><span class="number">1<span class="sep">. </span></span>Chapter1 from PartA</h1>
               </header>
               <p class="richtext">
                  
                  <p class="richtext"> Text in paragraph </p>
                  </p>
            </div>
            <div id="R_part1_ch2" class="chapter" db-label="2">
               <header>
                  <h1><span class="label">Chapter<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span><span class="number">2<span class="sep">. </span></span>Chapter2 from partA</h1>
               </header>
               <p>Another paragraph</p>
            </div>
         </article>
      </article>
      <article class="part">
         <h1 class="title">Part B</h1>
         <article id="R_part2" class="part">
            <header>
               <h1><span class="label">Part<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span><span class="number">II<span class="sep">. </span></span>Part B</h1>
            </header>
            <div id="R_part2_ch1" class="chapter" db-label="1">
               <header>
                  <h1><span class="label">Chapter<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span><span class="number">1<span class="sep">. </span></span>Chapter1 from PartB</h1>
               </header>
               <section id="R_part2_ch1_s1" class="section">
                  <header>
                     <h2><span class="number">1<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span>Section1 from Chapter1 of PartB</h2>
                  </header>
                  <p>a paragraph <a href="http://alink2" title="a link2">a link2</a></p>
               </section>
               <section id="R_part2_ch1_s2" class="section">
                  <header>
                     <h2><span class="number">2<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span>Section2 from Chapter1 of PartB</h2>
                  </header>
                  <p>a paragraph <a href="http://alink2" title="a link2">a link2</a></p>
               </section>
            </div>
         </article>
      </article>
   </article>
</main><nav xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="bottom"></nav>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the current output you get? Is that template not being used at all or does that output of  `print something e.g.` appear?

Comment: you are very right...I'm going to put it in my answer. Actually it doesn't do anything

Comment: We do not see the imported stylesheet, so cannot reproduce the problem. In general, if a template does not produce the prescribed output, then it was not instantiated. This could be because it was never applied - or not applied in the prescribed mode. Or that it could not find a node matching its pattern.

Comment: Can you match successfully on that wrapper element we saw in the resolution of the previous question (e.g. `<xsl:template match="db:info">...</xsl:template>`)? If you use e.g. oXygen or another IDE, you can use its features to select the part from the result tree (e.g. `h1><span class="label">Part<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span><span class="number">I<span class="sep">. </span></span>Part A</h1>`) and have it display the part of the XSLT that generated it.

Comment: `<xsl:template match="db:part" mode="m:docbook">...</xsl:template>` matches (m:docbook is important as otherwise doesn't match), `<xsl:template match="db:info" mode="m:docbook">...</xsl:template>` matches as well, similary for section...I'm using intelliJ, I will try the oXygen you're suggesting

Comment: It is hard to read through the various layers of code that compose those stylesheets, at some point it looks as if `db:title` is not only processed in the `m:docbook` mode but rather in the `m:title` mode so attempting to override `<xsl:template match="db:title" mode="m:title">...</xsl:template>` is worth a try.

Comment: Yes...it is you're right...Not sure how you got there. However it's only on the session layer and not on the part layer. This has as a result to show  `<span class="label">Chapter<span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></span><span class="number">1<span class="sep">. </span></span>` which is not what I want

Comment: Well, the software is documented, so with some reading of e.g. https://xsltng.docbook.org/guide/ and e.g. https://xsltng.docbook.org/guide/ch04.html#header-templates. I poked around in https://xsltng.docbook.org/explorer/index.html which is also helpful. I hope for you that someone (well, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055/norm) shows up during the next days that is a bit more familiar with the architecture and customization of those stylesheets.